# rspec - bug when I try to run multiple files including one that has a line-number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How can I run multiple specific spec files when one has a specific line number?

I have used:

```
rspec spec/models/billing/waiver_plan_class_spec.rb spec/models/billing/risk_tier_spec.rb spec/models/locations/parking_price_spec.rb
```

which works fine -

```
...........................

Finished in 12.57 seconds
27 examples, 0 failures
```

However when I add a line number, e.g.

```
rspec spec/models/billing/waiver_plan_class_spec.rb spec/models/billing/risk_tier_spec.rb spec/models/locations/parking_price_spec.rb:111
```

I just get:

```
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/models/locations/parking_price_spec.rb"=>[111]}}
.

Finished in 2.98 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Why does adding a line number to the third file seem to stop the other ones from running?

I have tried placing the file with the line number specific test in different positions on the line but it made no difference.  Wherever it is placed it is chosen as the only test example to run.

Comment: It seems that it is not supported. I run the tests in a similar fashion and I get the same result as you.

Comment: -l, --line LINE_NUMBER           Execute example group or example at given line.
                                     (does not work for dynamically generated examples)

From what I see, the line number is generic for all the examples you pass to rspec

Comment: And here is the bug on github.
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/621

Comment: Looks like it works ok in my current rspec 3 (2.14.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to a newer version of rspec, for example version 2.14.8+